# How to define a function include another function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, numpy

I have a working function:

```
def yo(a, b):
    return np.random.rand(a, b)
```

I want to define a new function `res` which calls `yo` and another function `reshape`:

```
def res(a, b):
    maa = []
    for t in yo(a, b):
        maa.append(t[0])
        return np.reshape(maa, (a, 1))   # Calling another function
```

But when I ran this function `res` as below, I face an error:

```
res(5,4)

cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (5,1)
```

When I removed the sub-function as below, the code works perfectly well.

```
maa = []
for t in yo(5, 4):
    maa.append(t[0])
print(np.reshape(maa,(5,1)))
```

Overall, I would like to understand how to define a function within a function.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Right now you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: And please post the complete error, not an abridged version. The type is important too

Answer (score 0):

You just have an indentation error, as suggested by Mad Physicist.  The `return` statement should be called once the for loop has finished:

```
def res(a, b):
    maa = []
    for t in yo(a, b):
        maa.append(t[0])
    return np.reshape(maa, (a, 1)) # Notice the indentation on this line
```

This will return the same result as when you 'don't use `def`'.  The reason the error occurs is because `np.reshape` is trying to operate only on a single row of the array outputted by `yo`.